# getSupportFragmentManager in Service,Android studio

Tags: android, android-activity, service

How can i get access to `getSupportFragmentManager(support.v4.app)` inside of Service in order to open dialogfragment from service
I've tried: `((Activity) getApplicationContext()).getSupportFragmentManager()` didn't work, but `((Activity) getApplicationContext()).getFragmentManager()` works.
Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i get access to getSupportFragmentManager(support.v4.app) inside of Service in order to open dialogfragment from service

You can't. Either:

- Start a dialog-themed activity from the service, or
- Use an event bus (greenrobot's EventBus, `LocalBroadcastManager`, Square's Otto) to raise an event from your service that your activity (if it exists) can pick up, and it can display the dialog

Comment: @AidaIsay: You cannot call `getFragmentManager()` on a `Service`.